# Computer doesn’t boot on first boot after cutting off power

Tags: windows-10, boot

As the title says, there’s a problem with one Windows 10 desktop computer I’m maintaining. The person using it uses a switch to cut off the power to the computer every time when they are done using it. This is done after already have shut it down from the start menu. This causes the computer not to boot on the first try and you need to forcibly shut down the computer by holding down the power button for five seconds. The second boot launches the computer normally.  The part where it gets stuck is the beginning, it doesn’t even show the Windows logo.

However if I shut down the computer through the start menu, and do not cut off the power afterwards, it will boot normally. The problem occurs only when doing a fresh boot after turning on the power and cutting the electricity to it.

To make it more random, sometimes after cutting off the power for a few minutes and then turning the computer on again starts it up normally.

I’ve tried turning off the smart boot from the settings. I’ve also fiddled with some settings in the BIOS but no avail.

Any ideas what could be causing the problem? It’s not the end of the world as the computer still boots but requiring to boot it twice every single time is quite bothersome.

System specs:
- CPU: Intel i5 6600k
- GPU: Integrated
- MOBO: [Asustek H-170 Pro](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/H170-PRO/specifications/)

Comment: Never shut down a computer using a power switch you have described. Always shut down a Windows 10 computer with the software button. Windows 10 does alot of computing even when you don't see activity. The hard disk can become very corrupt. Even BIOS may not be able to find the disc. I suggest you run a disk scan on it now, and have it check the hard disk fully.

Comment: @Asutekku is there any particular reason why this person doesn't like to shut their computer down properly?

Comment: I'm surprised it's lasted so long with such a relatively small issue. I'd honestly expect something to have been permanently & irreparably damaged by now.

Comment: This is a user problem, not a technical problem.  There is no proper technical solution for shutting down the computer improperly.  It's like a driver with a company car who insists on stopping the car by driving into a wall instead of using the brakes.  You don't fix that problem by reinforcing the bumper.  The solution is to educate the user, and maybe physically remove the external power switch.

Comment: @vssher I mean they do shut down the computer normally but afterwards cut off the power. So the computer has already been shut down when switching off the power. I’ve clarified the op.

Answer (score 2):

Have your user test something.

Have them hold down the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key while they click on Shut Down.  Let the machine shut down completely, then turn off power at the wall.

Windows 10 does something to make it look as if it boots faster; it does not completely shut down unless you do the first sentence of the second paragraph above.  This is described in https://www.thewindowsclub.com/make-windows-startup-run-shutdown-faster .

If that helps, then turn off the Fast Startup option. You will see this setting in Control Panel > Power Options > Choose what the power buttons do > Shutdown settings. That alteration will make sure Windows 10 completely shuts down at shut down.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, [the user is not actually shutting down](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13770/windows-shut-down-sleep-hibernate-your-pc), i.e. complete shutdown or hibernating, but is actually using sleep mode.

Sleep puts the processor in a low-power state, but it still requires *some* energy. Shut the power, and it must go through a full reboot afterwards.

To be able to safely power down, use hibernate for faster startup, or use full shutdown. The following two scripts can be run as Administrator to do so:

```
rem to enable Hibernate and then do so
powercfg -h on
shutdown /h  


rem to disable Hibernate and then shut down
powercfg -h off
shutdown /s /t 0
```